# How can I catch exception on bash file exit unnormally?

Tags: c++, linux, bash, exception, exit

Here I get a bash file b.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ ! -f somefile.txt ]; then
       ..................
fi
```

in the bash file ,I try to check whether somefile called "somefile.txt" exist, if not, I would consider it as an error and exit.

And I run this bash file in c++:

```
::system("sh b.sh")
```

What should I fill in the "..............." in that bash file and what should I do in c++ code to catch exception when the "somefile.txt" is not found.

Comment: You could also ensure that `somefile.txt` exists within the C++ program before calling bash...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put:

```
exit 1
```

in the script -- by convention, any non-zero exit code is considered failure.

In the C++ code, `system()` returns the termination status of the command. See the documentation of [`wait()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/wait) for details of interpreting this, or you can just check if it's non-zero if you want to know if there was any error.